# Colon or em-dash when asking a question with multiple choices

Tags: questions, punctuation

I am trying to ask a questions like these:

1. > Which security should I buy: a foreign-listed bond issue with a five-letter ticker ending with "Q", or a domestically-listed convertible preferred share issue with a five-letter ticker ending with "A"?

   Is my use of the colon correct? Should I have used an em-dash instead? For example: "Which security should I buy — a foreign-listed ...".
2. > Which one do people usually buy — the first one, or the second?

   Is my use of the em-dash correct, or should I have used an em-dash instead?

Comment: The colon is correct, as is @codi6's rework of the sentence below.  Both are good.  The emdash isn't really appropriate.

Comment: (Also this use example hurts my heart, as an American, on this particular day.  O_o)

Answer (score 1):

The : is more correct. Either is understandable. Though if you're going for *really* correct, you're better off with:

Should I buy a foreign-listed bond issue with a five-letter ticker ending with "Q", or a domestically-listed convertible preferred share issue with a five-letter ticker ending with "A"?

Comment: I disagree. The version with the colon has the virtue of separating a long sentence into more digestible pieces.